# Compare folders and export modified files

Tags: svn, git, version-control, tortoisesvn, diff

I was wondering if anyone could help me with the following. I work remotely with other software developers on the same project. I use subversion and tortoise to manage my code. I don't think the other developers do the same.

This creates problems when we try and share code, because we have to figure out which files were modified so we don't overwrite each others changes. Is there a program that I can use to compare two folders and have it mark which files are modified and export those files to a new directory?

The closest thing I have found was a program called DiffMerge. It finds the files that changed between the folders, but I have to manually go through the list, copy the paths and copy those files individually. It would be awesome if I could export those changed files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) will do what you are describing.
And, they give a free 30-day trial.

It is litteraly as-easy-as:

```
View -> Show Differences,
Right Click -> Copy To Folder
```

However, I think if you are using Git, it should be doing the branching and merging for you, if you are using it properly...

Answer (score 3):

This is what exactly SVN is for. I think you should convice other developers to use repository. Dont even colloborate with them until they start using it

Comment: LOL! Only in a perfect world :)

Answer (score 0):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is also very good if you're on Windows. It will let you copy and replace individual files or folders, as well as export diffs in an archive, which seems like its what you're looking for.

oh yeah - its free and open source.